# Similar to I2P and Tor with http/socks proxies

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, i2p

I am trying to measure different TCP packets delay that are transferred through various anonymity networks. For that purpose, I need some anonymity networks that use either socks or http proxies, just like TOR and I2P does, so I can route traffic through the network...

I checked most of the famous anonymity networks, but most of them are just protocols or doesn't support proxying applications (Freenet) or operating systems based on TOR (Tails OS), so are not suitable for my case.

Does anybody has to suggest other anonymity networks, where I can route applications through them, like i did with TOR and I2P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually a lot of anonymous networks that can make tunnels in a low-latency fashion. However, many of them are originally designed for file-sharing and thus require some modifications to be done in order to tunnel a pure TCP connection. [GNUnet](https://gnunet.org) is one running (with TCP tunneling capabilities), and also see [Unblock](https://github.com/UWNetworksLab/OneSwarm) (defunct), [Tribler](https://tribler.org/) (not supporting TCP tunneling) and [anoNet](http://anonet.org) (just a lot of VPNs).

Answer (score 0):

[The OP's question is perhaps off-topic as it isn't specifically about Tor, but rather other similar technologies. Also, without knowing which "famous" networks have been checked, it's difficult to know what to suggest.]

The high-level [Tor design document](https://svn.torproject.org/svn/projects/design-paper/tor-design.html) might be a good place to start, specifically the second section, entitled *Related work*.

This details the other anonymity systems which were taken into consideration when Tor was designed. It's possible that some of these are no longer supported or have an insufficient user base for them to be serviceable. Others still will never have been implemented, but were rather academic exercises, so mileage may vary.

With regards to which of the mentioned technologies operate at the transport layer (or specifically use TCP), and which, if any, use proxies, I'll leave that to the OP to investigate further.

Comment: i saw other posts here about i2p before posting...there is also a freenet tag...aren't all these irrelevant?? I also mentioned that there shouldn't be many networks satisfying my needs so what's the point mentioned what famous networks have been checked while i said Tor and i2p are what i am looking for and Freenet isn't...unhelpful answer...

Comment: When you said _"I've checked most of the famous anonimity networks"_ it sounded like you had looked into _many_ networks, not just Tor, I2P and Freenet. And what's famous for one person might not be for another, it's subjective - that's all I meant. If the pointer to the design doc isn't helpful, that's fine - that's how the site works. Someone will probably have a better answer :)